# This code won't find authors page?

Tags: pages, author

I am using this code to display current users author page. However if the user has a space in their username it won't find the URL. How can I get the code to place a '-' if there is a space in the author's username.
Thanks

`<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ) . '"> My personal page</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . wp_login_url() . '" title="Login">Login</a>';
    }
?>`

Answer (score 2):

Building URLs to WP resources in this fashion is fragile and shouldn't be done.

You should use appropriate API function to generate the links, in this case probably [`get_author_posts_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_author_posts_url/).

Comment: Hey Rarst, Thanks for the info. I'm just not sure how to ask for the current (logged in users) get_author_posts_url() so that I can place that link on any page.

Comment: @user45381 look at the linked reference, the function accepts author's ID as first argument.

Comment: Oh dear I'm so sorry but I don't have the technical knowledge to pull this off. So I've looked at that linked reference and I have to first establish who the author ID.

Comment: so like use this first ? `<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Combining Rarst's answer with the code you posted would give you something like the following:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
   $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user_ID ); ?>">My Personal Page</a>
<?php } else { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
<?php }
```

Untested, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your help helgatheviking. There is people out there that really appreciate the expertise

Comment: If this is the answer, then don't forget to mark it as such.